# MySQL request from android error

Tags: java, android

I have MySQL database. I'm trying to get some data from android using PHP.

This is my PHP code: Here I'm trying to get User's info using his id.

```
    <?php
// array for JSON response
$response = array();

// include db connect class
require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';

// connecting to db
$db = new DB_CONNECT();

// check for post data
if (isset($_GET["id"])) {
    $id = $_GET['id'];


// get a product from products table
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM app WHERE vk_id = $id");
//echo $result;
if (!empty($result)) {
    // check for empty result
    if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {

        $result = mysql_fetch_array($result);

        $users = array();

        $product["id"] = $result["id"];
        $product["first_name"] = $result["first_name"];
        $product["last_name"] = $result["last_name"];
        $product["vk_id"] = $result["vk_id"];
        $product["points"] = $result["points"];
        // success
        $response["success"] = 1;

        // user node
        $response["users"] = array();

        array_push($response["users"], $product);

        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
    } else {
        // no product found
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "No product found";

        // echo no users JSON
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
} else {
    // no product found
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "No user found";

    // echo no users JSON
    echo json_encode($response);
}
} else {
    // required field is missing
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

Testing with browser gives seccess result, it means PHP code working fine

So, here is the Android part:

```
public class DB_read_by_id extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    Context context;
    private static String url_read_by_id = "http://women.egeshki.ru/blockphonedb/read_by_id.php";

    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";
    private static final String TAG_USERS = "users";
    private static final String TAG_POINTS = "points";


    JSONArray users = null;
    String vk_id;
    String points;

    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

    public DB_read_by_id(String _vk_id, Context _context) {
        vk_id = _vk_id;
        context = _context;
        url_read_by_id += "?id=" + vk_id;
        Log.e("DB_read_by_id", "Constructor");
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

        // getting JSON string from URL
        JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_read_by_id, "GET", params);
        Log.e("DB_read_by_id", "doInBackground");
        Log.e("DB_read_by_id: ", url_read_by_id);
        Log.e("DB_read_by_id json ", json.toString());
        // Check your log cat for JSON response
        //Log.e("Users_all: ", json.toString());
        try {
            // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
            String message = json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
            users = json.getJSONArray(TAG_USERS);

            Log.e("DB_read_by_id", "Attempt to get from db");
            if (success == 1) {
                JSONObject c = users.getJSONObject(0);
                points = c.getString(TAG_POINTS);
                Log.e("DB_read_by_id Points", points);
            } else if (message.equals("No user found")) {
                Log.e("DB_read_by_id", "No user found");
            } else if (message.equals("Required field(s) is missing")) {
                Log.e("DB_read_by_id", "Required field(s) is missing");
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Here is the logcat:

```
com.example.myapplication E/DB_read_by_id﹕ Constructor
com.example.myapplication E/DB_read_by_id﹕ doInBackground
com.example.myapplication E/DB_read_by_id:﹕ http://women.egeshki.ru/blockphonedb/read_by_id.php?id=150923434
com.example.myapplication E/DB_read_by_id json﹕ {"message":"No user found","success":0}
```

When I test from browser the link, which I get from logcat it's againg working fine. But from android it gives me an error. **The problem is the link is ok, but android gives an error**

Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you didn't send the id to server

```
   List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    //add this
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id","the value here));//
        // getting JSON string from URL
        JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_read_by_id, "GET", params);
```

Edit :after reading your comments
i think the problem is that you use your parametre in the link instead off using the right way .. just try to use this :

```
  List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        //add this
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id","150923434"));//
            // getting JSON string from URL
            JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_read_by_id, "GET", params);
```

try this and report

Comment: I added it to the link in constructor. Here the link from logcat: com.example.myapplication E/DB_read_by_id:﹕ http://women.egeshki.ru/blockphonedb/read_by_id.php?id=150923434

Comment: Resource id #3{"success":1,"users":[{"id":"45","first_name":"\u0416\u0430\u043c\u0431\u044b\u043b","last_name":"\u0415\u0440\u043c\u0430\u0433\u0430\u043c\u0431\u0435\u0442","vk_id":"150923434","points":"0"}]}

Comment: so what is the problem now ?

Comment: The problem is the link is ok, but android gives an error

Comment: what is the error ? does the app carsh  -and did you echo this -> 
 
Resource id #3 ?

Comment: No, app is not crashing. It gives me "No user found" error. It means json gives that. How it could be? The same link, browser and anroid gives different results?

Comment: in php code .. add some echo .. exemple "echo $id "  .. "echo here we are in line 4" ... just to follow how does that work ok